# Directive using timeout not waiting for animation to finish

Tags: angularjs, timeout

This "focusMe" directive using the $timeout service does not wait for my modal to finish loading, so the animation is choppy. The input box should be automatically focused so the user does not have to click the box (or press tab) to enter their badge number.

I've attempted to do my own hacky fixes, and found two directives online that people said worked for them. I've included the best attempt I made [in this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3WTPop3E6FwrQnBIQJZf?p=preview)

Here is the broken directive:

```
signout.directive('focusMe', ['$timeout', '$parse', function ($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        // scope: true,   // optionally create a child scope
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.focusMe);
            scope.$watch(model, function (value) {
                console.log('value=', value);
                if (value === true) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        element[0].focus();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here's a visualization of this issue:

[Choppy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh2Wf.jpg)

[image]

[Smooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qctu.jpg)

[image]

My desired result is the directive waiting for animation to finish, then immediately focus on the input field for easy entry.

Comment: @georgeawg thanks again for the edit!!

Comment: Had to fix up the plunker a little to get it to work, but there doesn't seem to be an issue with the focus and the animation.  Yes, the box is focused before the animation finishes, but the animation is pretty smooth. http://plnkr.co/edit/1n7vrXdLkItxIl8p6I5e?p=preview

Comment: @kendavidson thank you for the response! it works in the plnkr, but when transitioning through router from my welcome.html to signout.html it's always choppy with this focus directive. I just gave it another try in my application and it's still delivering the choppy result in the above gif :/

Comment: ui-router or ngRoute?

Comment: @kendavidson ngRoute, which I need to use in my application seeing that I came into the project when it was already in a finished state, so I'm working within certain confines.

Comment: No judgement, I get taking over legacy code.  Updated the plunker with ngRoute, seems to be smooth even with the focus.  Can't compare to your live code since you only posted a small subset.  But doesn't seem to be impacted by `focus-me="true"`